# Tengo un problema con sweetAlert

Tags: javascript, php, sql, visual-studio

Estoy implementando `sweetAlert` a un proyecto de práctica que tengo, pero no me funciona como quiero.

Antes de implementar el `sweetAlert` hice una validación a mi formulario que no permita eliminar si el registro está siendo utilizada en otra entidad.

Quiero implementar el sweetAlert al proyecto y al dar click en el boton borrar me salga el mensaje de confirmación del `SweetAlert`, le doy ok y si es que el registro está siendo usado me salte el otro mensaje, pero un mensaje simple con boostrap, adjunto fotos y código!

Gracias!

```
  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-data-placement="top" title="Eliminar datos" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="smspersona()">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
  </a>
```

Probé llamando la función en `js` dentro del boton eliminar, pero no pasa nada:

```
function smspersona(ruc_persona) {
    swal({
    title: "Realmente quiere eliminar el registro?",
    text: "",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
  }).then((willDelete) => {
    if (willDelete) {
      swal("Eliminando Registro", {
        icon: "success",
      });
    } else {
  swal("Se ha cancelado la accion");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de la función, declare una variable llamada **registroEstaSiendoUtilizado** este indicara si el registro está siendo utilizado en otra entidad.

Luego, se muestra una alerta de SweetAlert con un título que dice "Realmente quiere eliminar el registro?" y un botón de confirmación para que el usuario pueda decidir si desea o no eliminar el registro.

espero que te sirva gracias :D

```
function smspersona(ruc_persona) {
  var registroEstaSiendoUtilizado = false;
  swal({
    title: "Realmente quiere eliminar el registro?",
    text: "",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
  }).then((willdelete) => {
    if (willdelete) {
      // Aquí puedes validar si el registro está siendo utilizado en otra entidad
      // Si está siendo utilizado, muestra un mensaje de error con Bootstrap
      if (registroEstaSiendoUtilizado) {
        $("#mensajeError").removeClass("hidden");
      } 
      else {
        swal("Eliminando Registro", {
          icon: "success",
        });
      }
    }
    else {
      swal("Se ha cancelado la acción");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: hola amigo, como estàs, disculpa, pero no entiendo tu respuesta, podrìas explicarme mejor si no es mucho pedir?

Comment: Bueno la variable registroEstaSiendoUtilizado se utiliza para verificar si el registro que se está intentando eliminar está siendo utilizado en otra entidad, como una tabla de la base de datos o en otra parte de la aplicación. Si el registro está siendo utilizado, se muestra un mensaje de error para informar al usuario que no se puede eliminar el registro en este momento.
algo asi entendi sobre tu pregunta amigo